# How Can I Reduce the Sensitivity on Responding to Mouse Events when Sliding Rows and Columns Around?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, 2d-games

I've been playing around trying to develop "casual games" lately, and I've in particular been wanting to do something with grids and colored tiles. I've got a demo project I'm working on called 'Kolourz' in which you just slide rows and columns around to try to get all the colors in line (or whatever; it's a dumb game).

I got all that to work okay, but what I'm running into is that whenever I hold down the mouse button and "swipe" in a direction it gets wildly carried away with moving the tiles! There seems to be a little more control going left or right than up or down, but I think that's just because of manual dexterity.

Here's the code to detect the mouse events:

```
$('.tile').mousedown(function(e1){
   e1.preventDefault();
    
    $('.tile').on('mousemove', function (event) {
        if (event.buttons==1){
            let targetCell = event.target.id;
            console.log(targetCell);
        if (typeof(last_position.x) != 'undefined') {
            var deltaX = last_position.x - event.offsetX,
                deltaY = last_position.y - event.offsetY;
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY) && deltaX > 0) {
                //left
                moveLeft(targetCell);
                targetCell="";
            } else if (Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY) && deltaX < 0) {
                //right
                moveRight(targetCell);
                targetCell="";
            } else if (Math.abs(deltaY) > Math.abs(deltaX) && deltaY > 0) {
                //up
                moveUp(targetCell);
                targetCell="";
            } else if (Math.abs(deltaY) > Math.abs(deltaX) && deltaY < 0) {
                //down
                moveDown(targetCell);
                targetCell="";                
            }
          
        }
        last_position = {
            x : event.offsetX,
            y : event.offsetY
        };
        }
    });
    
});     

  $('.tile').mouseup(function(){
    $(this).unbind("mousemove");
    $(this).unbind("mousedown");
});
```

And here's the code to respond:

```
const moveRight = (rowCol) => {
    let tempId = rowCol.split("-");
    let row = tempId[0];

    let tempColor = $(`#${row}-7`).css('background-color');

    for (let i=colorArray.length;i>0;i--) {
        $(`#${row}-${i}`).css('background-color',$(`#${row}-${i-1}`).css('background-color'));
    }

    $(`#${row}-0`).css('background-color',tempColor);
}


const moveLeft = (rowCol) => {
    let tempId = rowCol.split("-");
    let row = tempId[0];

    let tempColor = $(`#${row}-0`).css('background-color');

    for (let i=0;i<colorArray.length-1;i++){
        $(`#${row}-${i}`).css('background-color',$(`#${row}-${i+1}`).css('background-color'));
    }

    $(`#${row}-7`).css('background-color',tempColor);
}

const moveUp = (rowCol) => {
    let tempId = rowCol.split("-");
    let col = tempId[1];

    let tempColor = $(`#0-${col}`).css('background-color');

    for (let i = 0; i< colorArray.length-1;i++) {
        $(`#${i}-${col}`).css('background-color',$(`#${i+1}-${col}`).css('background-color'));
    }

    $(`#7-${col}`).css('background-color',tempColor);
}

const moveDown = (rowCol) => {
    let tempId = rowCol.split("-");
    let col = tempId[1];

    let tempColor = $(`#7-${col}`).css('background-color');

    for (let i = colorArray.length-1;i>0;i--) {
        $(`#${i}-${col}`).css('background-color',$(`#${i-1}-${col}`).css('background-color'));
    }

    $(`#0-${col}`).css('background-color',tempColor);
}
```

I just took a bunch of divs, gave them an ID to correspond to their row and column, then when the player "swipes" a row by clicking the mouse and dragging it calls the function to move that row. That function parses the id back into rows and columns and cycles the colors. But it's moving *way* too fast!

[Here's the repo with the full code](https://github.com/crashdaddy/kolourz)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've solved the problem in your game by just requiring two clicks (one for the tile you want to move, then the direction to move it in).

Some ideas on how to achieve what you want with the swipe:

1. You can clamp the amount you allow to move because of one mousemove. Clamping to one or two grid cells worth of distance might help if you are going for smooth scrolling.
2. You can limit the number of move that happen per-swipe to one. You could do this by setting a flag so the first time you move you don't allow any other flags, or be deregistering the 'onmousemove' function after you have handled one move.